# Cakephp naming convention for table name

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a table named job and is not plural but I was wondering if there is a way to overcome this so that cake can pickup singular table names.

I cannot change the table name as it is also used by other API's

Is there a way to do this in Cakephp?

Comment: seems silly to name a table with a singular. unless the table only ever contains one row?

Comment: ...or it's reserved for a single prophet? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the useTable attribute of the model.

```
var $useTable = 'job';
```